# bootstrap date-range on symfony 5 using the controller

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-forms, bootstrap-datepicker, symfony5

I'm trying to add a date-range input (who is a double date-picker input) using bootstrap date-range.

From the "bootstrap date-range" documentation they explain that I need this structure :

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

I'm using my controller to send parameters to the view.
Do you think it's possible to do it without editing the view (twig) and can you explain me how?

My current controller :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($recording)
                     ->add('starting_date',  DateType::class, [
                        'widget'=>'single_text',
                        'html5'=>false,
                        'attr'=>['class'=>'js-datepicker'],
                        'format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        'label'=>'Starting time',
                        'row_attr'=>[
                            'class'=>'input-daterange'
                        ]
                     ])
                     ->add('ending_date', DateType::class, [
                        'widget'=>'single_text',
                        'html5'=>false,
                        'attr'=>['class'=>'js-datepicker'],
                        'format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        'label'=>'Ending time',
                        'row_attr'=>[
                            'class'=>'input-daterange'
                        ]
                     ])
```

The problem is that each input is added on a specific div... but I need both of inputs on a single one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this case as follow:

First, I create a form with the 2 date fields :

```
      <?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BookingSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dateMin', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
            ])
            ->add('dateMax', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then, create the form in controller:

```
      /**
     * @Route("/bookings-for-date", name="bookings_for_date")
     */
    public function bookingForDates(Request $request, BookingRepository $bookingRepository)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(BookingSearchType::class);
        $bookings = [];
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $bookings = $bookingRepository->findBookingsBetweenDates($form['dateMin']->getData(), $form['dateMax']->getData());
        }
        return $this->render('report/bookings_for_date.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'bookings' => $bookings,
        ]);
    }
```

Then, in the view, I display only the widget wrapped with the correct wrapping div:

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    {{ form_widget(form.dateMin) }}
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    {{ form_widget(form.dateMax) }}
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And finally, the js:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker, .input-daterange').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        language: 'fr',
        todayHighlight: true,
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    });
});
```